# How would I slowly print the first three points, reject letters, and only accept numbers?

Tags: javascript, python, feed

## **How would I slowly print the first three points, reject letters, and only accept numbers?

```
import random
import struct

print("Welcome to Guess the Number!")
print("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.")
print("Can you guess what it is?")

number = random.randint(1, 100)
guesses = 0
# Has to be 0 else the game will never end.

while True:
    guess = int(input("Enter your guess: "))
    guesses += 1
# Not to change this else the game will never end.

    if guess == number:
        print(f"Congratulations ;)! You guessed the number in {guesses} guesses!")
        break
    elif guess < number:
        print("too low. try again.")
    else:
        print("TOO HIGH!. TRY AGAIN.")
    if guess > 100:
        print("Great, the best way to guess a number between 1 and 100 is make a guess out of range!")
```

Just numbers and slow print for first three points but python won't let me.

Comment: Why does this have the [javascript] tag?

Comment: "python won't let me" What do you mean by this?

Comment: What do you mean by "slowly" printing?

Answer (score 0):

This simulates slow printing and checks whether the input is an integer string.

```
import random
import time
import sys

print("Welcome to Guess the Number!")
print("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.")
print("Can you guess what it is?")

def print_slow(str):
    for letter in str:
        print(letter, end='')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(.1)
    print("")
number = random.randint(1, 100)
guesses = 0
# Has to be 0 else the game will never end.

while True:
    guess = input("Enter your guess: ")
    if str.isdigit(guess):
        guess = int(guess)
    else:
        print("not an integer")
        continue
    guesses += 1
# Not to change this else the game will never end.

    if guess == number:
        print_slow(f"Congratulations ;)! You guessed the number in {guesses} guesses!")
        break
    elif guess < number:
        print_slow("too low. try again.")
    else:
        print_slow("TOO HIGH!. TRY AGAIN.")
    if guess > 100:
        print("Great, the best way to guess a number between 1 and 100 is make a guess out of range!")
```